# Efficient alternative to multiple joins with sums in SQL?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

Suppose I have the following schema:

**A** id, number

**B** id, number

**ids** id

And have a query which returns me what I want, as follows:

```
SELECT ids.id, Atotal.total, Btotal.total
FROM ids
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, SUM(number) as total
    FROM A
    GROUP BY id
) Atotal
ON Atotal.id = ids.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, SUM(number) as total
    FROM B
    GROUP BY id
) Btotal
ON Btotal.id = ids.id
```

i.e, we return for each id in **ids** the sum of number for each of A and B over that id.

I know this is terribly inefficient, but what are my alternatives, and why/how would they be more efficient?

I feel like I might be able to use IN here, but I don't want to go ahead and use it without knowing exactly why it would be better, and to what extent. I've done some googling, but couldn't find anything similar to my problem.

(also, if there are any good materials that would help me become more efficient with my SQL, they would be much appreciated!)

Comment: if you want tips for perfomance you have to provide your `explain analyze` result so we can compare.

Comment: why do you use `ids` table ? does it contain combined range of `id`s from `A` and `B` ?

Comment: @Dmitry I guess some ID's arent in Table A or some arent in Table B. That is why he use `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: I dont think there is a better way. You need calculate two different values and join them together.

Comment: Your query is fine.  Why do you think it is terribly inefficient?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes, the idea was some IDs wouldn't be in tables A or B; the schema was really just meant to be used as an example, though.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hmm, my tutor said my answer (i.e the query) to a similar, but more complex problem was very inefficient. I guess he must've been referring to my overall approach (which was pretty unorthodox) instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be fine.  You can compare the performance to a subquery approach:

```
select i.id,
       (select sum(a.number) from A where a.id = i.id) as ATotal,
       (select sum(b.number) from B where b.id = i.id) as BTotal
from ids i;
```

Of particular interest is what happens when you have indexes on `A(id, number)` and `B(id, number)`.  I'm not sure if this is better in Postgres, but correlated subqueries do perform better in some databases under some circumstances.